# Display Details for Individual Items inside Tooltip on Mouse Hover

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display the details within a tooltip for each item in my index view. I would like the tooltip to appear when the mouse hovers over an items name. Currently I have some javascript and an view to go along with it. Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Details Javascript:

```
$(document).load(function () {
for (var count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: "#j" + count,
        content: function () {
            return $("#i" + count).text();
        }
    });
  };
});
```

Index View:

```
 <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Software Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SoftNameSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("License Type", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LicenseType, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("End Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.EndDateSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <noscript id="i@(count)">@Html.Partial("_SoftwareDetails", (WBLA.Models.SoftwareLicense)item)</noscript>
                <td id="j@(count)">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SoftwareName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LicenseType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.SoftwareID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.SoftwareID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.SoftwareID })
                </td>
            </tr>
            count++;
        }
    </table>
```

** EDIT **

I forgot to mention what I would like to show inside the tooltip. I would like to load a partial, which displays the relevant information for each item in my index view.

Partial Details View:

```
@model WBLA.Models.SoftwareLicense

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SoftwareName)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SoftwareName)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SoftwareKey)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SoftwareKey)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LicenseFilePath)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LicenseFilePath)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LicenseType)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LicenseType)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NotifyTime)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NotifyTime)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConsumerEmail)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ConsumerEmail)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntryEmail)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EntryEmail)
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*** EDIT 8/03/2016 ***

The title for the tooltip-tagged  displays, however, my partial will not load within the tooltip.

Updated SoftwareDetails.js:

```
$(function () {
    var url = '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="SoftwareDetails", controller="SoftwareLicense"})';
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: "td.myToolTips",
        content: function (callback) {
            $.get(url + "?id=" + $(this).data("id"))
             .done(function (r) {
                 callback(r);
             });
        }
    });

});
```

Updated Index View:

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Software Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SoftNameSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("License Type", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LicenseType, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("End Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.EndDateSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="myToolTips" data-id="@item.SoftwareID" title="Loading in a second..">
                    @item.SoftwareName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LicenseType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.SoftwareID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.SoftwareID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.SoftwareID })
                </td>
            </tr>
            //count++;
        }
    </table>
```

Updated SoftwareDetails Action:

```
public ActionResult SoftwareDetails(int id)
    {
        SoftwareLicense temp = db.SoftwareLicenses.Find(id);

        return PartialView("SoftwareDetails", temp);
    }
```

Result from URL Test (For Partial):
[Partial Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AczM.png)

Comment: What you want to show in the tool tip ? A simple text ? a property value of your model item in the loop ?

Comment: @Shyju I have added to my question, my apologies for the lack of specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to render the tool tip partial view for all items when the page loads. You may get it on as needed basis. You can do this by making an ajax call and passing a unique id for the record user is hovering on currently.

Start by keeping a data attribute in your tr for the unique id.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="myToolTips" data-id="@item.SoftwareID" title="@item.SoftwareName">
       <td>@item.SoftwareName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

and you can enable tooltip for the table rows with the css class myToolTips.

```
$(function () {

    $(document).tooltip({
                         items: "tr.myToolTips",
                         content: function (callback) {
                                    $.get('/Home/SoftwareDetails/' + $(this).data("id"))
                                     .done(function (r) {
                                                 callback(r);
                                     });
                         }
    });

});
```

Assuming you have an action method called `SoftwareDetails` which accepts the id and return the partial view

```
public ActionResult SoftwareDetails(int id)
{
  return Content("Toolip for "+id);
  // to do : Return the partial view for the markup you want (for the id)
}
```

Comment: I have implemented your code into my project and no luck. The tool tip only displays what I had set as the title in <tr>'s title attribute.

Comment: Check whether you have any js errors in your browser console.

Comment: It should work if you do not have other js errors in the page. [Here is a totally working dot net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F8xi7l) for your reference.

Comment: Please see my latest edit to my question. Also, thank you for creating the fiddle!

Comment: In my answer i am returning a string content. you can simply replace it with partial view response. It should simply work as long as you do not have any errors in that partial view( try to access the url (of the ajax call) in a browser and you can verify whether it has any errors.

Comment: It displays the partial properly, see bottom section of question. For whatever reason, I cannot get it to display the partial within in tooltip at runtime. It will only display "Loading in a second.."

Comment: When you try to access the url in the browser, it displays properly ?

Comment: I assume your partial view might be erroring out. You need to fix that. With the exact same code from the answer, it works fine for me. Here is the screenshot http://imgur.com/zMGppee